# Next-Auth authentication to Django Rest Framework with JWT and Route Handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have a Django project, for which I've decided to add Next.JS frontend. I set-up DRF authentication with JWT:

```
$ curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
      "username": "user1",
      "password": "strongpassword"
  }' 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/auth/login/'
{"access":"eyJhbG...","refresh":"eyJhbG...","user":{"pk":1,"username":"user1","email":"","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}}
```

I've configured Next-Auth in my frontend:

```
// frontend/auth.ts

import type {
  GetServerSidePropsContext,
  NextApiRequest,
  NextApiResponse,
} from "next";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "axios";

const BACKEND_ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME = 45 * 60; // 45 minutes
const BACKEND_REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME = 6 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 6 days

const getCurrentEpochTime = () => {
  return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
};

export const authOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: BACKEND_REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME,
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const response = await axios({
            url: process.env.NEXTAUTH_BACKEND_URL + "auth/login/",
            method: "post",
            data: credentials,
          });
          const data = response.data;
          if (data) return data;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ user, token, account }) {
      // If `user` and `account` are set that means it is a login event
      if (user && account) {
        let backendResponse: any =
          account.provider === "credentials" ? user : account.meta;
        token["user"] = backendResponse.user;
        token["access_token"] = backendResponse.access;
        token["refresh_token"] = backendResponse.refresh;
        token["ref"] = getCurrentEpochTime() + BACKEND_ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME;
        return token;
      }
      // Refresh the backend token if necessary
      if (getCurrentEpochTime() > token["ref"]) {
        const response = await axios({
          method: "post",
          url: process.env.NEXTAUTH_BACKEND_URL + "auth/token/refresh/",
          data: {
            refresh: token["refresh_token"],
          },
        });
        token["access_token"] = response.data.access;
        token["refresh_token"] = response.data.refresh;
        token["ref"] = getCurrentEpochTime() + BACKEND_ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME;
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({ token }) {
      return token;
    },
  },
} satisfies NextAuthOptions;

export function auth(
  ...args:
    | [GetServerSidePropsContext["req"], GetServerSidePropsContext["res"]]
    | [NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse]
    | []
) {
  return getServerSession(...args, authOptions);
}
```

Added route handlers:

```
//  frontend/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/auth";
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

And middleware:

```
// frontend/middleware.ts

import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth(
  function middleware(req) {
    console.log(req.nextauth.token);
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => !!token,
    },
  }
);

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*"] };
```

Create a login page:

```
// frontend/app/login/page.tsx

import LoginForm from "@/app/ui/login-form";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { auth } from "@/auth";

export default async function LoginPage() {
  const session = await auth();

  if (session) {
    redirect(`/dashboard`);
  }

  return (
    <main className="flex items-center justify-center md:h-screen">
      <div className="relative mx-auto flex w-full max-w-[400px] flex-col space-y-2.5 p-4 md:-mt-32">
        <LoginForm />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

And a login form (showing just the important parts here):

```
// frontend/app/ui/login-form.tsx

"use client";

import { Button } from "@/app/ui/button";
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import { authenticate } from "../lib/actions";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function LoginForm() {
  const [errorMessage, dispatch] = useFormState(authenticate, undefined);
  const router = useRouter();

  if (errorMessage === "ok") {
    router.push("/dashboard");
  }

  return (
    <form action={dispatch}>
              ...
              <input                
                id="username"
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="Username"
                required
              ...
              <input
                id="password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
                required
                minLength={6}
              />
        ...
        <LoginButton />
        <div>
          {errorMessage && errorMessage != "ok" && (
              <p>{errorMessage}</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

function LoginButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <Button aria-disabled={pending} disabled={pending}>
      Log in
    </Button>
  );
}
```

And defined `authenticate` function:

```
// frontend/app/lib/actions.ts

"use client";

import { signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export async function authenticate(
  prevState: string | undefined,
  formData: FormData
) {
  try {
    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      username: formData.get("username"),
      password: formData.get("password"),
      redirect: false,
    });
    if (res && res.status === 401) {
      return "Wrong username or password";
    } else if (res && res.status != 200 && res.status != 201) {
      return "Something went wrong";
    } else {
      return "ok";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return "Something went wrong";
    }
    throw error;
  }
}

export async function logOut() {
  try {
    const res = await signOut();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) {
      return "Something went wrong";
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

So, if I get sent to login page from inside dashboard my url looks like this `http://127.0.0.1:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fdashboard%2Fmachines%2Funits`. How can I redirect back to `callbackUrl` after successful login?